# requests module hangs after coming out of sleep on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-requests

When I take my computer out of sleep mode and try to run a python script using the requests module, it inevitably hangs. Everything else works fine. Restarting the computer allows requests to work again.

This is probably some kind of socket issue between windows and the requests module, but how can I prevent this ?

Comment: How long are you waiting after sleep ends to run the script?  Do you know you have a valid connection.  Sometimes after sleeping my corporate network connections loose the minds but can be reset by switching to airplane more or disconnecting and reconnection the Ethernet cable.  Alternatively, would you like some python code to prevent your Windows computer from sleeping while you run a script?

Comment: I know the connection works because I've posted this question :) And no, sleeping is the point, I don't want my computer to run for nothing while I'm having a meal, for example. But I'd also like to be able to run python scripts when I'm back...

Answer (score 0):

Requests library doesn't use a default timeout value. In the [advanced usage docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/) you can find the following information:

> Most requests to external servers should have a timeout attached, in case the server is not responding in a timely manner. By default, requests do not time out unless a timeout value is set explicitly. **Without a timeout, your code may hang for minutes or more**.

To avoid that behavior, just add the timeout in your requests as in the example:

```py
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=5)
```

The timeout will make the request to stop the forever execution and then you can add some handling for that case. You can also make use of the [HTTPAdapter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/?highlight=retry#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter) to handle the retries automatically:

```py
import requests
s = requests.Session()
a = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
s.mount('http://', a)
r = s.get(url, timeout=10)
```

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't resolve the actual problem that the module doesn't work anymore while everything else does.

Comment: It will stop the forever taking requests execution, and then you can trap this error in a try clause (or even handle to try again for x times).

Comment: Again, the goal is not to ignore the issue, it's to know why it happens and solve it.

Comment: You asked by how to prevent the behavior. Using the adapter and timeout is not about ignoring the error but handling it instead.

Comment: The most reasonable cause to this is due to the network is not ready when the script is executed, and since there's no timeouts in the requests it won't finish executing. Putting some logic in your code will help you to clarify if that is the case. Additionally you can configure windows to keep the network working when pc sleeps.

Comment: The network does work. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to write this question yesterday. Literally every other piece of software I've tried could access the internet no problem ; the fault lies with the requests module here.